# Angular with Bootstrap - getting redundant horiz scrollbar

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on an application in Angular. One of my components has the following template HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Info</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a>Data</a></li>                    
        </ul>
        <br>

        <div class="dataModel">
            <!--This div is creating a horizontal scrollbar -->
        </div>    
    </div>      
</div>
```

The **css** associated with `dataModel` class is as follows:

```
.dataModel{
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

When the `height` of this div is **below `50px`, I do not get a horizontal scrollbar**, however, any value above `50px` creates a horizontal scrollbar, which is unexpected, since the `width` is untouched.

I though of setting `height` to `auto`, but that would defeat the purpose of `overflow-y`

I suspect that the bootstrap classes are **maintaining an aspect ratio** on the `div`, which may be why changing the height affects the width. **Is that the case ?**

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by doing the following change:

```
<div class="row-fluid panel panel-primary">
```

in the first line of the component html. The rest remains the same.